# Update a value in the nested JsonNode

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to update the `expiryDate` variable in the nested JsonObject to the current date, the structure of the JSON is the following:

```
{
    "expiryDate" : {
        "type" : "String",
        "value" : "31-12-2019"
    }
}
```

I've successfully read the JSON but can put the new property only on the top-level, instead of updating the `expiryDate.value` property:

```
JsonNode data = new ObjectMapper().readTree(dataString);
String expiryDate = data.get("expiryDate").get("value").textValue();
((ObjectNode) data).put("05-02-2020");
```

How can I update the nested property?

Comment: What is `processData` ?

Comment: @YCF_L, sorry, that was a typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: You can use `set` or `replace` functions. `((ObjectNode) data.get("expiryDate").get("value")).set("05-02-2020");`

Comment: @stud3nt set took the fieldName and a value as `JsonNode` not a String, not just the value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```
JsonNode data = new ObjectMapper().readTree(dataString);
((ObjectNode) data.get("expiryDate")).put("value", "05-02-2020");
```

Where :

- `((ObjectNode) data.get("expiryDate"))` you get the parent, and then
- `put("value", "05-02-2020")` change the value of the nested node

**Output**

```
{"expiryDate":{"type":"String","value":"05-02-2020"}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can user ObjectNode .put and update the existing value below is the tested code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {
        String datString = "{ \"expiryDate\" : { \"type\" : \"String\", \"value\" : \"31-12-2019\" } } ";
        JsonNode data = new ObjectMapper().readTree(datString);
        System.out.println(" before update json"+data);
        String expiryDate = data.get("expiryDate").get("value").textValue();
        ((ObjectNode) data.get("expiryDate")).put("value", "05-02-2020");
        System.out.println(" updated json "+data);
    } }
```

Comment: This is the best answer, because it uses only Jackson! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for providing import section, because auto-save can import wrong class which will cause class cast issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
var data={
    "expiryDate" : {
        "type" : "String",
        "value" : "31-12-2019",
    },
} 

data.expiryDate.value ="01-01-2020"
```

there is the method inside an expiry date.

Comment: It will be helpfull for us all if you add a bit of description to your answer

Comment: ..The OP use Java